# Apache Spark - Multiple spark context error

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming

I am getting the Multiple spark context error.

Can anybody help me in resolving this?

If I take `parsing.take(1)` its running fine. but it is giving Multiple spark context error when i do `take > 2` in the last line of my code.

Any help is much appreciated

```
from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark import SparkContext

sc = SparkContext()

from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

############ IRIS DataSet ##############
iris= sc.textFile("hdfs:///user/edureka/IRIS.csv")
testset,trainingset = iris.randomSplit([1,2])

import numpy as np
def parse_interaction(line):
    line_split = line.split(",")
    # keep just numeric and logical values
    symbolic_indexes = [4] # Specify the columns which has the String values
    features = [item for i,item in enumerate(line_split) if i not in symbolic_indexes]
    return np.array([float(x) for x in features])


def parse_interaction_label(line):
    line_split = line.split(",")
    # keep just numeric and logical values
    symbolic_indexes = [4] # Specify the columns which has the String values
    label = [item for i,item in enumerate(line_split) if i in symbolic_indexes]
    return np.array([float(x) for x in label])


features_train = trainingset.map(parse_interaction)

labels_train = trainingset.map(parse_interaction_label)

features_test=testset.map(parse_interaction)

labels_test=testset.map(parse_interaction_label)

def parse_interaction_with_key(line):
    line_split = line.split(",")
    # keep just numeric and logical values
    #symbolic_indexes = [4] # Specify the columns which has the String values
    features_label = [item for i,item in enumerate(line_split)]
    return (np.array([float(x) for x in features_label]))

features_train_label = trainingset.map(parse_interaction_with_key)
features_test_label= testset.map(parse_interaction_with_key)

product=features_train_label.cartesian(features_test_label)


import math
def distancecal(line):
    training_label=line[0]
    training=training_label[0:4] # hardcoded the Training Column
    train_label = training_label[-1]
    testing_label=line[1]
    test=testing_label[0:4]  # Hardcoded the Testing column Modified the Testing Column
    stringtest=str(line[1])
    points=zip(training,test)
    diffs_squared_distance = [pow(a - b, 2) for (a, b) in points]
    score = math.sqrt(sum(diffs_squared_distance))
    training_label = np.append(training_label,score)
    return (stringtest,training_label)

training_label_test_score = product.map(distancecal)

keyvalue=training_label_test_score.groupByKey().mapValues(list)

def sortingvalue(l):
    from pyspark import SparkConf
    from pyspark import SparkContext
    #conf1 = SparkConf()
    #conf1.setAppName('Sorting Job Stream')
    #conf1.set("spark.ui.port", "36000")
    #conf1.set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "true")
    sc1 = SparkContext()
    v = sc1.parallelize(l)
    vSorted = v.sortBy(lambda a: a[5])
    return(vSorted.collect())


def parsekeyvalueforsorting(line):
    key=line[0]
    cdata=line[1]
    scdata=sortingvalue(cdata)
    return (key,scdata)


parsing=keyvalue.map(parsekeyvalueforsorting)
print(parsing.take(2))
```

This is my list is first element is string and the second one is list of array:

```
        [('[ 0.2  1.4  3.4  5.2  0. ]', [array([ 0.2,  1.4,  3. ,  4.9,  0. ,  **0.5**]), array([ 0.2       ,  1.3       ,  3.2       ,  4.7       ,  0.        ,**0.54772256**]), array([ 0.2       ,  1.4       ,  3.6       ,  5.        ,  0.        ,
        0.28284271]), array([ 0.4       ,  1.7       ,  3.9       ,  5.4       ,  0.        ,
        0.64807407]), array([ 0.2      ,  1.5      ,  3.4      ,  5.       ,  0.       ,
        0.2236068]), array([ 0.2       ,  1.4       ,  2.9       ,  4.4       ,  0.        ,
        0.94339811]), array([ 0.1      ,  1.5      ,  3.1      ,  4.9      ,  0.       ,
        0.4472136]), array([ 0.2       ,  1.5       ,  3.7       ,  5.4       ,  0.        ,
        0.37416574]), array([ 0.2      ,  1.6      ,  3.4      ,  4.8      ,  0.       ,
        0.4472136]), array([ 0.1       ,  1.4       ,  3.        ,  4.8       ,  0.        ,
        0.57445626]), array([ 0.1       ,  1.1       ,  3.        ,  4.3       ,  0.        ,
        1.03440804]), array([ 0.4       ,  1.5       ,  4.4       ,  5.7       ,  0.        ,
        1.14017543]), array([ 0.4       ,  1.3       ,  3.9       ,  5.4       ,  0.        ,
        0.58309519]), array([ 0.3       ,  1.7       ,  3.8       ,  5.7       ,  0.        ,
        0.71414284]), array([ 0.3       ,  1.5       ,  3.8       ,  5.1       ,  0.        ,
        0.43588989]), array([ 0.2       ,  1.7       ,  3.4       ,  5.4       ,  0.        ,
        0.36055513]), array([ 0.4       ,  1.5       ,  3.7       ,  5.1       ,  0.        ,
        0.38729833]), array([ 0.2       ,  1.        ,  3.6       ,  4.6       ,  0.        ,
        0.74833148]), array([ 0.5      ,  1.7      ,  3.3      ,  5.1      ,  0.       ,
        0.4472136]), array([ 0.2       ,  1.9       ,  3.4       ,  4.8       ,  0.        ,
        0.64031242]), array([ 0.2       ,  1.6       ,  3.        ,  5.        ,  0.        ,
        0.48989795]), array([ 0.4       ,  1.6       ,  3.4       ,  5.        ,  0.        ,
        0.34641016]), array([ 0.2       ,  1.5       ,  3.5       ,  5.2       ,  0.        ,
        0.14142136]), array([ 0.4,  1.5,  3.4,  5.4,  0. ,  0.3]), array([ 0.2       ,  1.5       ,  3.1       ,  4.9       ,  0.        ,
        0.43588989]), array([ 0.2       ,  1.2       ,  3.2       ,  5.        ,  0.        ,
        0.34641016]), array([ 0.2       ,  1.3       ,  3.5       ,  5.5       ,  0.        ,
        0.33166248]), array([ 0.2       ,  1.5       ,  3.4       ,  5.1       ,  0.        ,
        0.14142136]), array([ 0.3      ,  1.3      ,  2.3      ,  4.5      ,  0.       ,
        1.3114877]), array([ 0.4     ,  1.9     ,  3.8     ,  5.1     ,  0.      ,  0.678233]), array([ 0.3       ,  1.4       ,  3.        ,  4.8       ,  0.        ,
        0.57445626]), array([ 0.2       ,  1.6       ,  3.8       ,  5.1       ,  0.        ,
        0.45825757]), array([ 0.2       ,  1.4       ,  3.2       ,  4.6       ,  0.        ,
        0.63245553]), array([ 0.2       ,  1.5       ,  3.7       ,  5.3       ,  0.        ,
        0.33166248]), array([ 0.2      ,  1.4      ,  3.3      ,  5.       ,  0.       ,
        0.2236068]), array([ 1.3       ,  4.        ,  2.3       ,  5.5       ,  1.        ,
        3.04466747]), array([ 1.5       ,  4.6       ,  2.8       ,  6.5       ,  1.        ,
        3.73898382]), array([ 1.3       ,  4.6       ,  2.9       ,  6.6       ,  1.        ,
        3.69594372]), array([ 1.4       ,  3.9       ,  2.7       ,  5.2       ,  1.        ,
        2.86006993]), array([ 1.5       ,  4.2       ,  3.        ,  5.9       ,  1.        ,
        3.19061123]), array([ 1.        ,  4.        ,  2.2       ,  6.        ,  1.        ,
        3.07896086]), array([ 1.3       ,  3.6       ,  2.9       ,  5.6       ,  1.        ,
        2.54165301]), array([ 1.5       ,  4.5       ,  3.        ,  5.6       ,  1.        ,
        3.40881211]), array([ 1.        ,  4.1       ,  2.7       ,  5.8       ,  1.        ,
        2.96310648]), array([ 1.5      ,  4.5      ,  2.2      ,  6.2      ,  1.       ,
        3.7067506]), array([ 1.3       ,  4.        ,  2.8       ,  6.1       ,  1.        ,
        3.02324329]), array([ 1.5       ,  4.9       ,  2.5       ,  6.3       ,  1.        ,
        3.99499687]), array([ 1.2      ,  4.7      ,  2.8      ,  6.1      ,  1.       ,
        3.6138622]), array([ 1.3       ,  4.3       ,  2.9       ,  6.4       ,  1.        ,
        3.36303434]), array([ 1.4       ,  4.8       ,  2.8       ,  6.8       ,  1.        ,
        3.98998747]), array([ 1.7       ,  5.        ,  3.        ,  6.7       ,  1.        ,
        4.19761837]), array([ 1.5       ,  4.5       ,  2.9       ,  6.        ,  1.        ,
        3.49141805]), array([ 1.        ,  3.5       ,  2.6       ,  5.7       ,  1.        ,
        2.43721152]), array([ 1.1      ,  3.8      ,  2.4      ,  5.5      ,  1.       ,
        2.7676705]), array([ 1.        ,  3.7       ,  2.4       ,  5.5       ,  1.        ,
        2.64952826]), array([ 1.2       ,  3.9       ,  2.7       ,  5.8       ,  1.        ,
        2.84604989]), array([ 1.6       ,  5.1       ,  2.7       ,  6.        ,  1.        ,
        4.09633983]), array([ 1.5       ,  4.5       ,  3.        ,  5.4       ,  1.        ,
        3.39116499]), array([ 1.3       ,  4.4       ,  2.3       ,  6.3       ,  1.        ,
        3.55387113]), array([ 1.3       ,  4.        ,  2.5       ,  5.5       ,  1.        ,
        2.97825452]), array([ 1.2       ,  4.4       ,  2.6       ,  5.5       ,  1.        ,
        3.27566787]), array([ 1.        ,  3.3       ,  2.3       ,  5.        ,  1.        ,
        2.34520788]), array([ 1.3      ,  4.2      ,  2.7      ,  5.6      ,  1.       ,
        3.1144823]), array([ 1.2       ,  4.2       ,  3.        ,  5.7       ,  1.        ,
        3.04138127]), array([ 1.3      ,  4.3      ,  2.9      ,  6.2      ,  1.       ,
        3.2969683]), array([ 2.5       ,  6.        ,  3.3       ,  6.3       ,  2.        ,
        5.26022813]), array([ 1.9       ,  5.1       ,  2.7       ,  5.8       ,  2.        ,
        4.17492515]), array([ 2.1       ,  5.9       ,  3.        ,  7.1       ,  2.        ,
        5.25642464]), array([ 1.8       ,  5.6       ,  2.9       ,  6.3       ,  2.        ,
        4.65403051]), array([ 2.2       ,  5.8       ,  3.        ,  6.5       ,  2.        ,
        5.02095608]), array([ 1.8      ,  6.3      ,  2.9      ,  7.3      ,  2.       ,
        5.5883808]), array([ 1.8      ,  5.8      ,  2.5      ,  6.7      ,  2.       ,
        4.9979996]), array([ 2.5       ,  6.1       ,  3.6       ,  7.2       ,  2.        ,
        5.60535458]), array([ 2.        ,  5.1       ,  3.2       ,  6.5       ,  2.        ,
        4.31972221]), array([ 1.9      ,  5.3      ,  2.7      ,  6.4      ,  2.       ,
        4.4754888]), array([ 2.1       ,  5.5       ,  3.        ,  6.8       ,  2.        ,
        4.81040539]), array([ 2.        ,  5.        ,  2.5       ,  5.7       ,  2.        ,
        4.15451562]), array([ 1.8       ,  5.5       ,  3.        ,  6.5       ,  2.        ,
        4.60651712]), array([ 2.2       ,  6.7       ,  3.8       ,  7.7       ,  2.        ,
        6.20483682]), array([ 2.3       ,  6.9       ,  2.6       ,  7.7       ,  2.        ,
        6.44592895]), array([ 1.5       ,  5.        ,  2.2       ,  6.        ,  2.        ,
        4.09023227]), array([ 2.       ,  4.9      ,  2.8      ,  5.6      ,  2.       ,
        4.0012498]), array([ 1.8       ,  4.9       ,  2.7       ,  6.3       ,  2.        ,
        4.06324993]), array([ 1.8       ,  6.        ,  3.2       ,  7.2       ,  2.        ,
        5.26877595]), array([ 1.6       ,  5.8       ,  3.        ,  7.2       ,  2.        ,
        5.04777179]), array([ 2.        ,  6.4       ,  3.8       ,  7.9       ,  2.        ,
        5.97411081]), array([ 2.2       ,  5.6       ,  2.8       ,  6.4       ,  2.        ,
        4.84148737]), array([ 1.5       ,  5.1       ,  2.8       ,  6.3       ,  2.        ,
        4.11703777]), array([ 2.3      ,  6.1      ,  3.       ,  7.7      ,  2.       ,
        5.7367238]), array([ 2.4       ,  5.6       ,  3.4       ,  6.3       ,  2.        ,
        4.86723741]), array([ 1.8       ,  5.5       ,  3.1       ,  6.4       ,  2.        ,
        4.57165178]), array([ 2.4       ,  5.6       ,  3.1       ,  6.7       ,  2.        ,
        4.98196748]), array([ 2.3       ,  5.1       ,  3.1       ,  6.9       ,  2.        ,
        4.59129611]), array([ 2.3       ,  5.9       ,  3.2       ,  6.8       ,  2.        ,
        5.22111099]), array([ 2.5       ,  5.7       ,  3.3       ,  6.7       ,  2.        ,
        5.10294033]), array([ 2.3       ,  5.2       ,  3.        ,  6.7       ,  2.        ,
        4.61085675]), array([ 1.9       ,  5.        ,  2.5       ,  6.3       ,  2.        ,
        4.22729228]), array([ 2.3       ,  5.4       ,  3.4       ,  6.2       ,  2.        ,
        4.62709412]), array([ 1.8       ,  5.1       ,  3.        ,  5.9       ,  2.        ,
        4.11096096])]), ('[ 0.3  1.4  3.4  4.6  0. ]', [array([ 0.2       ,  1.4       ,  3.        ,  4.9       ,  0.        ,
        0.50990195]), array([ 0.2       ,  1.3       ,  3.2       ,  4.7       ,  0.        ,
        0.26457513]), array([ 0.2       ,  1.4       ,  3.6       ,  5.        ,  0.        ,
        0.45825757]), array([ 0.4       ,  1.7       ,  3.9       ,  5.4       ,  0.        ,
        0.99498744]), array([ 0.2       ,  1.5       ,  3.4       ,  5.        ,  0.        ,
        0.42426407]), array([ 0.2       ,  1.4       ,  2.9       ,  4.4       ,  0.        ,
        0.54772256]), array([ 0.1       ,  1.5       ,  3.1       ,  4.9       ,  0.        ,
        0.47958315]), array([ 0.2      ,  1.5      ,  3.7      ,  5.4      ,  0.       ,
        0.8660254]), array([ 0.2,  1.6,  3.4,  4.8,  0. ,  0.3]), array([ 0.1       ,  1.4       ,  3.        ,  4.8       ,  0.        ,
        0.48989795]), array([ 0.1      ,  1.1      ,  3.       ,  4.3      ,  0.       ,
        0.6164414]), array([ 0.4       ,  1.5       ,  4.4       ,  5.7       ,  0.        ,
        1.49331845]), array([ 0.4      ,  1.3      ,  3.9      ,  5.4      ,  0.       ,
        0.9539392]), array([ 0.3      ,  1.7      ,  3.8      ,  5.7      ,  0.       ,
        1.2083046]), array([ 0.3       ,  1.5       ,  3.8       ,  5.1       ,  0.        ,
        0.64807407]), array([ 0.2       ,  1.7       ,  3.4       ,  5.4       ,  0.        ,
        0.86023253]), array([ 0.4,  1.5,  3.7,  5.1,  0. ,  0.6]), array([ 0.2       ,  1.        ,  3.6       ,  4.6       ,  0.        ,
        0.45825757]), array([ 0.5      ,  1.7      ,  3.3      ,  5.1      ,  0.       ,
        0.6244998]), array([ 0.2       ,  1.9       ,  3.4       ,  4.8       ,  0.        ,
        0.54772256]), array([ 0.2       ,  1.6       ,  3.        ,  5.        ,  0.        ,
        0.60827625]), array([ 0.4       ,  1.6       ,  3.4       ,  5.        ,  0.        ,
        0.45825757]), array([ 0.2      ,  1.5      ,  3.5      ,  5.2      ,  0.       ,
        0.6244998]), array([ 0.4       ,  1.5       ,  3.4       ,  5.4       ,  0.        ,
        0.81240384]), array([ 0.2      ,  1.5      ,  3.1      ,  4.9      ,  0.       ,
        0.4472136]), array([ 0.2,  1.2,  3.2,  5. ,  0. ,  0.5]), array([ 0.2       ,  1.3       ,  3.5       ,  5.5       ,  0.        ,
        0.91651514]), array([ 0.2       ,  1.5       ,  3.4       ,  5.1       ,  0.        ,
        0.51961524]), array([ 0.3       ,  1.3       ,  2.3       ,  4.5       ,  0.        ,
        1.10905365]), array([ 0.4       ,  1.9       ,  3.8       ,  5.1       ,  0.        ,
        0.81853528]), array([ 0.3      ,  1.4      ,  3.       ,  4.8      ,  0.       ,
        0.4472136]), array([ 0.2     ,  1.6     ,  3.8     ,  5.1     ,  0.      ,  0.678233]), array([ 0.2      ,  1.4      ,  3.2      ,  4.6      ,  0.       ,
        0.2236068]), array([ 0.2       ,  1.5       ,  3.7       ,  5.3       ,  0.        ,
        0.77459667]), array([ 0.2       ,  1.4       ,  3.3       ,  5.        ,  0.        ,
        0.42426407]), array([ 1.3       ,  4.        ,  2.3       ,  5.5       ,  1.        ,
        3.12729915]), array([ 1.5       ,  4.6       ,  2.8       ,  6.5       ,  1.        ,
        3.95600809]), array([ 1.3       ,  4.6       ,  2.9       ,  6.6       ,  1.        ,
        3.93573373]), array([ 1.4       ,  3.9       ,  2.7       ,  5.2       ,  1.        ,
        2.88270706]), array([ 1.5       ,  4.2       ,  3.        ,  5.9       ,  1.        ,
        3.33616546]), array([ 1.        ,  4.        ,  2.2       ,  6.        ,  1.        ,
        3.26343377]), array([ 1.3       ,  3.6       ,  2.9       ,  5.6       ,  1.        ,
        2.66270539]), array([ 1.5       ,  4.5       ,  3.        ,  5.6       ,  1.        ,
        3.49428104]), array([ 1.        ,  4.1       ,  2.7       ,  5.8       ,  1.        ,
        3.11608729]), array([ 1.5       ,  4.5       ,  2.2       ,  6.2       ,  1.        ,
        3.87943295]), array([ 1.3       ,  4.        ,  2.8       ,  6.1       ,  1.        ,
        3.22024844]), array([ 1.5       ,  4.9       ,  2.5       ,  6.3       ,  1.        ,
        4.17013189]), array([ 1.2       ,  4.7       ,  2.8       ,  6.1       ,  1.        ,
        3.78285606]), array([ 1.3     ,  4.3     ,  2.9     ,  6.4     ,  1.      ,  3.591657]), array([ 1.4       ,  4.8       ,  2.8       ,  6.8       ,  1.        ,
        4.23910368]), array([ 1.7       ,  5.        ,  3.        ,  6.7       ,  1.        ,
        4.41474801]), array([ 1.5       ,  4.5       ,  2.9       ,  6.        ,  1.        ,
        3.64142829]), array([ 1.        ,  3.5       ,  2.6       ,  5.7       ,  1.        ,
        2.59807621]), array([ 1.1       ,  3.8       ,  2.4       ,  5.5       ,  1.        ,
        2.86530976]), array([ 1.        ,  3.7       ,  2.4       ,  5.5       ,  1.        ,
        2.75499546]), array([ 1.2       ,  3.9       ,  2.7       ,  5.8       ,  1.        ,
        2.99833287]), array([ 1.6       ,  5.1       ,  2.7       ,  6.        ,  1.        ,
        4.22255847]), array([ 1.5      ,  4.5      ,  3.       ,  5.4      ,  1.       ,
        3.4423829]), array([ 1.3       ,  4.4       ,  2.3       ,  6.3       ,  1.        ,
        3.75499667]), array([ 1.3       ,  4.        ,  2.5       ,  5.5       ,  1.        ,
        3.06267857]), array([ 1.2       ,  4.4       ,  2.6       ,  5.5       ,  1.        ,
        3.35559235]), array([ 1.        ,  3.3       ,  2.3       ,  5.        ,  1.        ,
        2.33880311]), array([ 1.3       ,  4.2       ,  2.7       ,  5.6       ,  1.        ,
        3.21403174]), array([ 1.2       ,  4.2       ,  3.        ,  5.7       ,  1.        ,
        3.16543836]), array([ 1.3       ,  4.3       ,  2.9       ,  6.2       ,  1.        ,
        3.49571166]), array([ 2.5       ,  6.        ,  3.3       ,  6.3       ,  2.        ,
        5.37587202]), array([ 1.9       ,  5.1       ,  2.7       ,  5.8       ,  2.        ,
        4.26380112]), array([ 2.1       ,  5.9       ,  3.        ,  7.1       ,  2.        ,
        5.46808925]), array([ 1.8       ,  5.6       ,  2.9       ,  6.3       ,  2.        ,
        4.79895822]), array([ 2.2       ,  5.8       ,  3.        ,  6.5       ,  2.        ,
        5.17107339]), array([ 1.8       ,  6.3       ,  2.9       ,  7.3       ,  2.        ,
        5.81377674]), array([ 1.8       ,  5.8       ,  2.5       ,  6.7       ,  2.        ,
        5.17976833]), array([ 2.5       ,  6.1       ,  3.6       ,  7.2       ,  2.        ,
        5.80775344]), array([ 2.        ,  5.1       ,  3.2       ,  6.5       ,  2.        ,
        4.49777723]), array([ 1.9       ,  5.3       ,  2.7       ,  6.4       ,  2.        ,
        4.63680925]), array([ 2.1      ,  5.5      ,  3.       ,  6.8      ,  2.       ,
        5.0049975]), array([ 2.        ,  5.        ,  2.5       ,  5.7       ,  2.        ,
        4.22729228]), array([ 1.8       ,  5.5       ,  3.        ,  6.5       ,  2.        ,
        4.77807493]), array([ 2.2       ,  6.7       ,  3.8       ,  7.7       ,  2.        ,
        6.43972049]), array([ 2.3       ,  6.9       ,  2.6       ,  7.7       ,  2.        ,
        6.67083203]), array([ 1.5       ,  5.        ,  2.2       ,  6.        ,  2.        ,
        4.21900462]), array([ 2.       ,  4.9      ,  2.8      ,  5.6      ,  2.       ,
        4.0620192]), array([ 1.8      ,  4.9      ,  2.7      ,  6.3      ,  2.       ,
        4.2284749]), array([ 1.8       ,  6.        ,  3.2       ,  7.2       ,  2.        ,
        5.49636243]), array([ 1.6       ,  5.8       ,  3.        ,  7.2       ,  2.        ,
        5.28866713]), array([ 2.       ,  6.4      ,  3.8      ,  7.9      ,  2.       ,
        6.2401923]), array([ 2.2       ,  5.6       ,  2.8       ,  6.4       ,  2.        ,
        4.98497743]), array([ 1.5       ,  5.1       ,  2.8       ,  6.3       ,  2.        ,
        4.28719022]), array([ 2.3       ,  6.1       ,  3.        ,  7.7       ,  2.        ,
        5.98832197]), array([ 2.4      ,  5.6      ,  3.4      ,  6.3      ,  2.       ,
        4.9939964]), array([ 1.8       ,  5.5       ,  3.1       ,  6.4       ,  2.        ,
        4.73180727]), array([ 2.4       ,  5.6       ,  3.1       ,  6.7       ,  2.        ,
        5.15266921]), array([ 2.3       ,  5.1       ,  3.1       ,  6.9       ,  2.        ,
        4.80312398]), array([ 2.3       ,  5.9       ,  3.2       ,  6.8       ,  2.        ,
        5.39722151]), array([ 2.5       ,  5.7       ,  3.3       ,  6.7       ,  2.        ,
        5.26782688]), array([ 2.3       ,  5.2       ,  3.        ,  6.7       ,  2.        ,
        4.79687398]), array([ 1.9       ,  5.        ,  2.5       ,  6.3       ,  2.        ,
        4.38406204]), array([ 2.3       ,  5.4       ,  3.4       ,  6.2       ,  2.        ,
        4.74973683]), array([ 1.8       ,  5.1       ,  3.        ,  5.9       ,  2.        ,
        4.21781934])])]
```

I need to sort the second element of array based on the bold values (5th element) in all the list

Answer (score 0):

There are two hidden questions:

- Why do I get the error?
- How can I solve the problem?

**Answer: The reason for this error is:**

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html

> Only one SparkContext may be active per JVM. You must stop() the
>   active SparkContext before creating a new one.

The issue is being caused due to fact that **INSIDE** a `map` operation of a spark-context `parsing=keyvalue.map(parsekeyvalueforsorting)`
You are creating spark-context for each line.

This is the function which is called inside the `map` operation which creates a new spark-context for every line in `keyvalue`.

```
def sortingvalue(l):
    from pyspark import SparkConf
    from pyspark import SparkContext
    sc1 = SparkContext()
    v = sc1.parallelize(l)
    vSorted = v.sortBy(lambda a: a[5])
    return(vSorted.collect())
```

Briefly reviewing your code, it seems like the function takes a line, and sort it. It seems like it can be done easily in python without any need for spark.

This conflict spark requirement : "Only one SparkContext may be active per JVM"

**How can I solve the problem?**

*Rewriting this function as pure python should solve your error.*

In order to sort a list of arrays using python you can use python `sorted()` function with key which will point to the 5th element in the array:

```
sorted(l, key=lambda x: x[4])
```

Example input:

```
>>> myin = [([ 0.2,1.4,3.,4.9,0.3,0.5]), ([ 0.2,1.3,3.2,4.7,0.4,0.54772256]),([0.2,1.4,3.6,5.,0.1,0.28284271]), ([0.4,1.7,3.9,5.4,0.7,0.64807407]), ([0.2,1.5,3.4,5.,0.6,0.2236068])]
```

Result:

```
>>> sorted(myin,key = lambda x: x[4])
[[0.2, 1.4, 3.6, 5.0, 0.1, 0.28284271], [0.2, 1.4, 3.0, 4.9, 0.3, 0.5], [0.2, 1.3, 3.2, 4.7, 0.4, 0.54772256], [0.2, 1.5
, 3.4, 5.0, 0.6, 0.2236068], [0.4, 1.7, 3.9, 5.4, 0.7, 0.64807407]]
>>>
```

More info about [sorted() in python wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/#Key_Functions)

Note that your input holds the word "array" which should be removed in order to be used in `sorted()`

Comment: Hi Yaron, Thanks for your comment. sortBy function I am using is works only on the pyspark RDD which sorts the data. The list l contains lakhs of entries and I need to sort it . is there any efficient solution you can suggest

Comment: If you wull describe the needed sort functionality I might be able to help implement it in pure python

Comment: Hi Yaron, this is how my list is there

Comment: @Muthukumar - Do you have a lot of elements of type ("string",list-of-arrays) ? Do you need to sort the list-of-arrays by the 5th element?

Comment: @Muthukumar - I've provided an example of a pure Python function which sort elements of type list-of-arrays by the 5th element

Comment: Hi yaron, thanks for the code but it takes a more time to sort of the array length is is in 100000 any other solution to parallelize the sort

Comment: Please describe what is your input, what is the expected output, and the algorithm from input to output

Comment: Do you have a long list where each element in the list is ("string" , array of 1000000 arrays[6] of type floats)?

Comment: Yes correct I have string and long list of array and I need to sort on the last value of each arrays

Comment: Does your input have only one string + long list of arrays?

Comment: Yes string and long list of array (repeated)

Comment: 1 string and 100 of array of list

Comment: @Muthukumar - reviewing the long discussion here I suggest that you'll open a new question which will describe what is your input, expected output, and algorithm, and what you tried to do.

Comment: @Muthukumar - if you think that I've answered the question "Why do I get the error?" please accept my answer